# Scrolling across several plots in an html report using R Markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Using R Markdown, I would like to generate an html report where I could browse multiple plots in the same 'window', e.g. using a scrollbar with two arrow buttons to print the previous and next plot. I have found several questions asking how to scroll within a large figure or image, but could not identify a solution to scroll between several plots.
For example, knitting the Rmd code below would generate three graphs on the top of each other. Which code should I use to make them scrollable?

**EDIT:** I need a 'single page view' to easily compare two consecutive plots, i.e. I should be able to move the scrollbar in a discrete, not continuous, way.

````
---
title: "Test multiple plots"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Generating multiple plots

I would like these three plots to be at the same location, and to switch between them by pressing buttons or sliding a scroll bar in the html document.

```{r plots, echo = F}
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 1)
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 2)
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 3)
```
````

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

````
---
title: "Test multiple plots"
output: html_document
---

<style>
.vscroll-plot {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(width=200)
```

## Generating multiple plots

I would like these three plots to be at the same location, and to switch between them by pressing buttons or sliding a scroll bar in the html document.

<div class="vscroll-plot">

```{r plots, echo = F}
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 1)
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 2)
plot(0, pch = 16, col = 3)
```

</div>
````

Output:

[image]

You will see that there is a vertical scrollbar. You can change the height and width in the `style` to make the view bigger or smaller.

Comment: Thank you Quinten, it works but does not allow me to navigate in a discrete way through each plot, like a single page view. I have edited my question accordingly.